# Xamarin iOS App crash on device but run well on simulator

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Hello I made an app who is running well on the simulator.
When i upload the app on my iphone X the app crash and here is the crash log file:

Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184a7c2e8 **pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184b95748 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 360
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001849eb060 __abort + 152
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001849eafc8 __abort + 0
4   DropCounterFree                 0x00000001030d62c8 xamarin_printf + 4891336 (runtime.m:2335)
5   DropCounterFree                 0x0000000103016fe4 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 4108260 (exception.c:1119)
6   DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102fdbd94 mono_handle_exception_internal + 3866004 (mini-exceptions.c:2002)
7   DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102fdab2c mono_handle_exception + 3861292 (mini-exceptions.c:2288)
8   DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102fd34ec mono_arm_throw_exception + 3831020 (exceptions-arm64.c:411)
9   DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102d7ff18 throw_exception + 168
10  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102c6bf24 System_Number_ParseDouble_string_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_Globalization_NumberFormatInfo + 404
11  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102c5fe44 double_Parse_string_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_Globalization_NumberFormatInfo + 36
12  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102c5fe08 double_Parse_string_System_IFormatProvider + 40
13  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102c5936c System_Convert_ToDouble_string + 44
14  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102c3c578 DropCounterFree_secondViewController_ViewDidLoad + 66936 (/:1)
15  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102d63668 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 248
16  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102fea568 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 3925352 (mini-runtime.c:2777)
17  DropCounterFree                 0x000000010304d81c do_runtime_invoke + 4331548 (object.c:2849)
18  DropCounterFree                 0x000000010304d778 mono_runtime_invoke + 4331384 (object.c:3002)
19  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102c30204 native_to_managed_trampoline_1(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, unsigned int) + 16900 (registrar.m:25)
20  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102c33b18 -[secondViewController viewDidLoad] + 31512 (registrar.m:1924)
21  UIKit                           0x000000018e521a00 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1040
22  UIKit                           0x000000018e5215d8 -[UIViewController view] + 28
23  UIKit                           0x000000018e6a4a88 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1148
24  UIKit                           0x000000018e5c7b94 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
25  UIKit                           0x000000018e5c77d8 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 164
26  UIKit                           0x000000018e5c76d8 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188
27  UIKit                           0x000000018e51ee18 -[UIView+ 52760 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1276
28  QuartzCore                      0x0000000188fab948 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
29  QuartzCore                      0x0000000188fafad0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1206992 (CA::Transaction*) + 332
30  QuartzCore                      0x0000000188f1c31c CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 602908 (CA::Transaction*) + 336
31  QuartzCore                      0x0000000188f43b40 CA::Transaction::commit+ 764736 () + 540
32  QuartzCore                      0x0000000188f44980 CA::Transaction::observer_callback+ 768384 (__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
33  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184f0ecdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 32
34  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184f0c694 **CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
35  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184f0cc50 __CFRunLoopRun + 1292
36  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184e2cc58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
37  GraphicsServices                0x0000000186cd8f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
38  UIKit                           0x000000018e5855c4 UIApplicationMain + 236
39  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102e066b0 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 1943216 (/:1)
40  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102dd528c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 1741452 (UIApplication.cs:79)
41  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102dd524c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 1741388 (UIApplication.cs:63)
42  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102c38e44 DropCounterFree_Application_Main_string** + 52804 (/:1)
43  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102d63668 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 248
44  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102fea568 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 3925352 (mini-runtime.c:2777)
45  DropCounterFree                 0x000000010304d81c do_runtime_invoke + 4331548 (object.c:2849)
46  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001030504ec do_exec_main_checked + 4343020 (object.c:4726)
47  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102fd2cf4 mono_jit_exec + 3828980 (driver.g.c:1040)
48  DropCounterFree                 0x00000001030dc0c0 xamarin_main + 4915392 (monotouch-main.m:0)
49  DropCounterFree                 0x0000000102c38d98 main + 52632 (main.m:43)
50  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018494c56c start + 4

It looks to be corralated with Convert string to double.

If some one have a good advice?

Comment: `System_Globalization_NumberStyles` : What is the `string` value that is trying to be parsed and what is the locale of the device set to?

Comment: hi, it's just 100.

Comment: what do you mean by local, excuse my ignorance i am a niewbie.

Comment: ok found it was a "." and "," problem in the string. But why it was working in the simulator?